# Regular expression to match a create table statement

Tags: java, regex

I have the following create table statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE db.my_table (
 ts TIMESTAMP OPTIONS (description = "This is 'a' (timestamp)"),
 id INT64 OPTIONS (description = 'id'),
 value STRING
) PARTITION BY ts, id
  CLUSTER BY id
  OPTIONS (description = 'test_(table)');
```

I want to extract several fields: `db`, `table name`, `column definitions` i.e. everything between  `(`, after db.my_table, and `)` before PARTITION BY. Then I want to extract the fields of PARTITION BY, CLUSTER BY and the text of the final description. The `PARTITION BY`, `CLUSTER BY` and `OPTIONS` expressions are optional, that is, any of them can appear or can be missing.

I used the following regex:

```
CREATE TABLE (\w+).(\w+) \(((?s).*)\)(?:\s+PARTITION BY ([^\n\r]+))?(?:\s+CLUSTER BY ([^\n\r]+))?(?:\s+OPTIONS \(description = ((?<Qt>'''|'|")(.*?)\k<Qt>))?;
```

[Demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/fw44Gv/1)

This works fine when the last `OPTIONS` expression is not defined, but when it is, it captures everything until the last `)` of `OPTIONS`. For example, this input is matched correctly:

```sql
CREATE TABLE db.my_table (
 ts TIMESTAMP OPTIONS (description = "This is 'a' (timestamp)"),
 id INT64 OPTIONS (description = 'id'),
 value STRING
) PARTITION BY ts, id
  CLUSTER BY id;
```

How can I fix it, so to match `OPTIONS` separately?

Comment: To handle your requirement robustly in the general case, you should look into using a library which can parse SQL statements.  Regex alone is a can of worms, and may not cover all edge cases.

Comment: For my use case, all the time this is the expected structure. So I don't need to cover more edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, regex is not the right tool for parsing SQL. This should be done with a proper SQL parser.

If however, the variation in the input string is limited (as you state in comments), then there are two things you could improve in your regex:

1. There is a missing `\)` in your pattern to match what follows in the `OPTIONS` clause.
2. To avoid that the third capture group reads beyond the closing bracket of the column definition part, you could take more control over nested brackets and string literals by replacing `((?s).*)` with `((?:\((?:"[^"]*"|[^)])*\)|[^)])*)`

   This will match (one level of) nested parentheses, and deal with quoted strings inside of them (double quoted), and will stop at any other closing parenthesis.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE (\w+).(\w+) \(((?:\((?:"[^"]*"|[^)])*\)|[^)])*)\)(?:\s+PARTITION BY ([^\n\r]+))?(?:\s+CLUSTER BY ([^\n\r]+))?(?:\s+OPTIONS \(description = ((?<Qt>'''|'|")(.*?)\k<Qt>)\))?;
```

Comment: It works as intended, thanks a lot! For this simple case I didn't want to use a 3rd party tool or library.